# Using T-SQL, I am creating a calculated column and I want to retrieve the value of the previous row of that column - is it possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to populate some data with some grouping.

DDL Script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TEMP 
(
    OTHERCOL VARCHAR(10),
    RANK_NO INT,
    TAG INT
)


INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('OC1',1,0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('OC1',2,0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('OC1',3,0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('OC2',1,0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('OC2',2,0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('OC2',3,9999)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('OC2',4,0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('OC2',5,0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('OC3',1,0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('OC3',2,0)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('OC3',3,0)
```

Using `DENSE_RANK` over `OTHERCOL`, I have got `FINAL_TAG` as shown here:

| OTHERCOL | RANK_NO | TAG | FINAL_TAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OC1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| OC1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| OC1 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| OC2 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| OC2 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| OC2 | 3 | 9999 | 2 |
| OC2 | 4 | 0 | 2 |
| OC2 | 5 | 0 | 2 |
| OC3 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| OC3 | 2 | 0 | 3 |
| OC3 | 3 | 0 | 3 |

However, I want the result to be as shown below in the desired value. I could achieve this in Excel, but I'm unable to so in SQL Server.

[Details of the activity done is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc112.png)

I have tried to use `SELECT CASE` but it is not working as the value is getting reset... Is there any way to so that we can update the values of variable and use the same based on the condition?

Comment: *"retrieve the value  of the previous row"* - sounds like you will need window function.

Comment: select *
, dense_rank() over(order by othercol) + sum(case when tag = 9999 then 1 else 0 end) over(order by othercol)
from #TEMP
perhaps

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired value by applying a conditional running total using analytic function `sum()` and `case` clause :

```
select *, DENSE_RANK() over (order by OTHERCOL) as FINAL_TAG,
          DENSE_RANK() over (order by OTHERCOL) 
          + sum(case when TAG > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(order by OTHERCOL, RANK_NO ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as DESIRED_VALUE
from #TEMP
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/BrRcSZLi)

Comment: `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` might be wise, in case there are duplicate `RANK_NO` values, it's also faster. I like your answer better than mine, it only requires a single sort.

Comment: this gives the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do first a conditional count of `Tag`, excluding (by nulling out) the cases where `Tag = 0`.

Then do `DENSE_RANK` using that column as another ordering column.

```sql
SELECT *,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY OTHERCOL, c)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      c = COUNT(NULLIF(TAG, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY OTHERCOL ORDER BY RANK_NO)
    FROM #TEMP t
) t;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/D-dH2Slc)